# Is there any workaround to apply more then one Effect on one UIElement in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, uielement

Is there any workaround to apply more then one Effect on one `UIElement` in WPF?
e.g.

```
<Button Content="Blurred (Radius=2)">
    <Button.Effect>
        <BlurEffect Radius="2"></BlurEffect>
    </Button.Effect>
</Button>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Following code explain, what do i mean. 
<Button Content="Blurred">
 <Button.Effect>
  <BlurEffect Radius="2"></BlurEffect>
 </Button.Effect>
</Button>
Unfortunately WPF allows us to use just one Effect at a time. I am asking for workaround for this problem. I have one in mind but want to see what people are using. May be my one is not so good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the `UIElement` in, say, a `Border`, and apply the additional effect to the `Border`.

```
  <Border>
    <Border.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect/>
     </Border.Effect>
     <Button Content="Blurred (Radius=2)">
       <Button.Effect>
         <BlurEffect Radius="2"></BlurEffect>
       </Button.Effect>
      </Button>
  </Border>
```

Comment: Thanks Samuel. Its saved my time and lot of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you might be interested in the [BitmapEffectGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.bitmapeffectgroup.aspx):

```
 <Button Content="Blurred (Radius=2)">
     <Button.Effect>
         <BitmapEffectGroup>
             <BlurEffect Radius="2"></BlurEffect>
         </BitmapEffectGroup>
     </Button.Effect>
 </Button>
```

Comment: BitmapEffects are obsolete as from WPF 3.5

Comment: Check the answer of Samuel. Its the alternative and not obsolete. But Thanks for ur help.